SwiftUI, How do I pass a value to a view that is presented on a sheet?
I am trying to pass a value to a subview that is presented on a sheet. The initial value is set to “Fred”. When a button is clicked, the value is changed to “Jane” after which the sheet is presented. Yikes! When the sheet appears the value is still “Fred”. What am I doing wrong?

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var firstName = "Fred"
    @State private var presentSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            firstName = "Jane"
            presentSheet.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("go to sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
            SubView(theName: firstName)
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    let theName: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("theName = \(theName)")
    }
}


Try setting theName as a @Binding value. Otherwise won't update
@Binding var theName: String


Thanks @Brogrammer. I also had to add $ wrapper to firstName when calling the SubView.

SubView doesn't need write access though. The downside is body will be called every time SubView is init because it cant compare bindings like it can simple values.

@Foul Plumbing Pls, set the answer as correct if it solved your issue, thanks!

It works to toggle the flag in an .onChange handler, instead of in the button action:
Button("go to sheet") {
    firstName = "Jane"
}
.onChange(of: firstName) {
    presentSheet.toggle()
}
.sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
    // ...
}

Alternatively, you could use the .sheet modifier that takes a binding to an Identifiable item, instead of a boolean flag:

sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)
Presents a sheet using the given item as a data source for the sheet’s content.

However, this means wrapping the string with an Identifiable wrapper:
struct ContentView: View {

    struct IdentifiableName: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let name: String
    }

    @State private var firstName = "Fred"
    @State private var sheetName: IdentifiableName?

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            firstName = "Jane"
            sheetName = IdentifiableName(name: firstName)
        } label: {
            Text("go to sheet")
        }
        .sheet(item: $sheetName) { sheetName in
            SubView(theName: sheetName.name)
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}


fyi the only reason this works is because now the firstName getter is called, you could do that without .onChange just with let _ = firstName at the top of body or .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) { [firstName] in

@malhal Thanks for the explanation. It would have been good to see that as another answer, shame the question was closed (especially since the referenced duplicate has gone for Binding as the accepted answer, which is not the best solution imo).
